# My current work item in TFS Team Explorer with git

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, team-explorer

I'm nearly very happy with the "my work" option in the Team Explorer in Visual Studio - just to see the list of work items, I'm assigned to - and to drag&drop one or two of them for my next commit (instead of search an typing work item numbers).

But since I'm on a TFS GIT project now, this point is missing - but where can I see my current work items in the git like UI of the Team Explorer in VST?

Comment: What do you mean? now in Visual Studio you don't have the team explorer option?

Comment: I've the Team Explorer. But with GIT as Source Control I don't have the Option "My Work" with the list of Work items assigned to me.

Comment: You don't have "My Work" in git, but you have "Work Items", can you see it?

Comment: Yes, and I can use queries there. But there is no drap&drop option to add one Work item from there to a commit as it can be done in "My Work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFVC and Git have different settings, that's by design. "`My Work`" is for TFVC and "`Work Items`" is for Git in the Team Explorer.

If you mean drag&drop work items to associate with commit in Git, then you can create a query to filter the work items, then drag&drop the work items to `Related Work items` in Team Explorer before submitting a commit...

[image]

If you just want to see your current work items in UI, then you can navigate to Work--> Work items, by default you will see all the work items `Assigned to me`, you can filter them by states, type etc...

[image]